# Garbage values in output

Tags: c++

I have a following program where in , I am trying to set wrong positions and i am getting garbage values in Average, Min & Max. Can we get NOVALUE if the array is of Non valid values as output

Comment: The error is on line 42. Seriously, it's hard to guess at the problem without seeing at least a little of the code that's causing it.

Comment: Can you show us your code? We won't steal it :D

Comment: @JerryCoffin Line 42 looks fine. Its line 41 thats causing the problem .

Answer (score 0):

No, you can't. Fix your program so that there are not invalid values.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is not well formulated, but i think i know what you mean.
Best is: do not add invalid values to you statistic.
This would destroy your statistic.

Next: record how many values you have added to your statistic. if it is 0 then the statistic is empty. This is especially important when you initialize your min, and max value with maximum or special  values, which will get overwritten when the first real value appreas.

Comment: Further you could accept (Check Mark)  the best answer, that one which helped you most.

Answer (score 0):

You can add a check for the case when you have "wrong positions" and then use a flag or store a distinct flag value in Average, Min and Max.